Deeper Contextual understanding of Jeremiah 5:4-5's use of the words "poor" Vs "great" & dichotomy between them

Jeremiah 5:4-5
New American Standard Bible 1995
4 Then I said, “They
are only the poor, They are foolish; For they do not know the way of
the Lord Or the ordinance of their God.
5 “I will go to the great And
will speak to them, For they know the way of the Lord And the
ordinance of their God.” But they too, with one accord, have broken
the yoke And burst the bonds.


Jeremiah 5:4-5
New King James Version
4 Therefore I said, “Surely
these are poor. They are foolish; For they do not know the way of the
Lord, The judgment of their God. 5 I will go to the great men and
speak to them, For they have known the way of the Lord, The judgment
of their God.” But these have altogether broken the yoke And burst the
bonds.


Jeremiah 5:4-5
English Standard Version
4 Then I said, “These are only the poor;
they have no sense; for they do not know the way of the Lord,
the justice of their God.
5 I will go to the great
and will speak to them, for they know the way of the Lord,
the justice of their God.” But they all alike had broken the yoke;
they had burst the bonds.


5:4-5 The Westminster Leningrad Codex 4
וַאֲנִ֣י אָמַ֔רְתִּי
אַךְ־דַּלִּ֖ים הֵ֑ם נוֹאֲל֕וּ כִּ֣י לֹ֤א יָדְעוּ֙ דֶּ֣רֶךְ יְהוָ֔ה
מִשְׁפַּ֖ט אֱלֹהֵיהֶֽם׃
5 אֵֽלֲכָה־לִּ֤י אֶל־הַגְּדֹלִים֙ וַאֲדַבְּרָ֣ה אוֹתָ֔ם כִּ֣י הֵ֗מָּה
יָדְעוּ֙ דֶּ֣רֶךְ יְהוָ֔ה מִשְׁפַּ֖ט אֱלֹהֵיהֶ֑ם אַ֣ךְ הֵ֤מָּה
יַחְדָּו֙ שָׁ֣בְרוּ עֹ֔ל נִתְּק֖וּ מוֹסֵרֽוֹת׃

URL links to Biblehub commentaries regarding said verses

https://biblehub.com/commentaries/jeremiah/5-4.htm
https://biblehub.com/commentaries/jeremiah/5-5.htm

I did skim through bible commentaries pertaining to the Jeremiah 5:4-5 bible verses But I would have liked it if said commentaries delved into if the term "poor" could be associated with the "spiritually poor" along with  the "financially poor"
Furthermore, could "poor" be associated with those who are "lower-class" or "classless" within this context?
Moreover, could "great" be associated with the arrogant who are Not necessarily "financially rich" and/or "upper-class", but rather just be "egomaniacs"?
Could someone please also give an explanation about the dichotomy between said terms within this context?
Please refer to the Old Testament Hebrew scripture in mind when answering.

The poor in the passage are the have-nots that lived in the land. Or, like you said, the lower-class of the society.
Jeremiah as the prophet foreseeing the judgement and distraction of the Kingdom of Judah, and its capital, makes the distinction between the educated rich and the poor. The exploitation of the impoverished by the elites was a blunt violation of the law. Together with the open idolatry, it was the main reason that led to the destruction and the Babylonian exile.
The rich and powerful were the ones to blame, because unlike the illiterate poor, they had the access to the law and could read it themselves. But instead of keeping it, they violated it by breaking the commandments and rewriting their meaning.

8 “ ‘How can you say, “We are wise, for we have the law of the Lord,”
when actually the lying pen of the scribes has handled it falsely? 9
The wise will be put to shame; they will be dismayed and trapped.
Since they have rejected the word of the Lord, what kind of wisdom do
they have? 10 Therefore I will give their wives to other men and their
fields to new owners. From the least to the greatest, all are greedy
for gain; prophets and priests alike, all practice deceit. 11 They
dress the wound of my people as though it were not serious. “Peace,
peace,” they say, when there is no peace. 12 Are they ashamed of their
detestable conduct? No, they have no shame at all; they do not even
know how to blush. So they will fall among the fallen; they will be
brought down when they are punished, says the Lord. (Jeremiah 8)

According to the law of Moses, the poor and the needy had a special place in the Israelite society. As brothers, they should have been helped and cared for. They were not.

9 “ ‘When you reap the harvest of your land, do not reap to the very
edges of your field or gather the gleanings of your harvest. 10 Do not
go over your vineyard a second time or pick up the grapes that have
fallen. Leave them for the poor and the foreigner. I am the Lord your
God. (Leviticus 19)
10 “For six years you are to sow your fields and harvest the crops, 11
but during the seventh year let the land lie unplowed and unused. Then
the poor among your people may get food from it, and the wild animals
may eat what is left. Do the same with your vineyard and your olive
grove. (Exodus 23)

Unfortunately, the sabbatical years were not kept. The land was not respected and treated as God's property. As a result, the poor could not get the food they needed.
The people neglected God's warnings from the past and paid for it dearly:

27 “ ‘If in spite of this you still do not listen to me but continue
to be hostile toward me, 28 then in my anger I will be hostile toward
you, and I myself will punish you for your sins seven times over. 29
You will eat the flesh of your sons and the flesh of your daughters.
30 I will destroy your high places, cut down your incense altars and
pile your dead bodies on the lifeless forms of your idols, and I will
abhor you. 31 I will turn your cities into ruins and lay waste your
sanctuaries, and I will take no delight in the pleasing aroma of your
offerings. 32 I myself will lay waste the land, so that your enemies
who live there will be appalled. 33 I will scatter you among the
nations and will draw out my sword and pursue you. Your land will be
laid waste, and your cities will lie in ruins. 34 Then the land will
enjoy its sabbath years all the time that it lies desolate and you are
in the country of your enemies; then the land will rest and enjoy its
sabbaths. 35 All the time that it lies desolate, the land will have
the rest it did not have during the sabbaths you lived in it.
(Leviticus 26)
15 The Lord, the God of their ancestors, sent word to them through his
messengers again and again, because he had pity on his people and on
his dwelling place. 16 But they mocked God’s messengers, despised his
words and scoffed at his prophets until the wrath of the Lord was
aroused against his people and there was no remedy. 17 He brought up
against them the king of the Babylonians, who killed their young men
with the sword in the sanctuary, and did not spare young men or young
women, the elderly or the infirm. God gave them all into the hands of
Nebuchadnezzar. 18 He carried to Babylon all the articles from the
temple of God, both large and small, and the treasures of the Lord’s
temple and the treasures of the king and his officials. 19 They set
fire to God’s temple and broke down the wall of Jerusalem; they burned
all the palaces and destroyed everything of value there. 20 He carried
into exile to Babylon the remnant, who escaped from the sword, and
they became servants to him and his successors until the kingdom of
Persia came to power. 21 The land enjoyed its sabbath rests; all the
time of its desolation it rested, until the seventy years were
completed in fulfillment of the word of the Lord spoken by Jeremiah.
(2 Chronicles 36)

And what about the poor? What happened to them? God compensated them through the same guy that was the instrument of His punishment:

8 The Babylonians set fire to the royal palace and the houses of the
people and broke down the walls of Jerusalem. 9 Nebuzaradan commander
of the imperial guard carried into exile to Babylon the people who
remained in the city, along with those who had gone over to him, and
the rest of the people. 10 But Nebuzaradan the commander of the guard
left behind in the land of Judah some of the poor people, who owned
nothing; and at that time he gave them vineyards and fields. (Jeremiah
39)


The first three verses of that chapter seem to give the meaning as to who those 'poor' were, as contrasted with 'the great' [men]. I went to the commentary with the translation I now quote from, but it only said the Hebrew for 'poor' is dal. It said about judgement of God that that equated with the justice of God. It did not make any comment about the great men. It did say that 'altogether' meant 'together, or with one accord'.
But the first three verses seem to explain verses 4 & 5.  See what you think (God speaking first):

"Run ye to and fro through the streets of Jerusalem, and see now, and
know, and seek in the broad places thereof, if ye can find a man, if
there be any that executeth judgment, that seeketh the truth; and I
will pardon it.
And although they say, 'The Lord liveth'; surely they swear falsely."
O Lord, are not Thine eyes upon the truth? Thou hast stricken them,
but they have not grieved; Thou hast consumed them, but they have
refused to receive correction: they have made their faces harder than
a rock; they have refused to return." Jeremiah 5:1-3 The Companion
Bible

Context therefore gives the answer that it is spiritual poverty the Lord is bringing to Jeremiah's attention. If there is only one man to be found who executes righteous judgment and seeks God's truth, God will pardon the sin of Jerusalem. In verse 4, those who do not know the just judgment of God are said to be "poor" and "foolish". But those who DO know the way of the Lord (verse 5) will be dealt with by the Lord.
Verse 5 alludes to who "a great man" is in God's reckoning - one who knows the ways of the Lord and his just judgments - great in knowledge and understanding of the Lord. But in this verse, such great men are found wanting - as one, they have not executed righteous judgment, nor sought God's truth (verse 1). Had there been even one such man, God would have spared the city from his judgment coming via the Babylonians. I hope this helps.
